# Finding the length of a valid substring in a string. C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to find out the length of the longest valid Substring. A valid Substring is one that contain atleast 1 upper case and no numbers. My code is not working can someone help thank you.

```
class Program

{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "a02caa3ThisIsValid1bC2a";

        Console.WriteLine("The longest valid substring is {0}", solution(S));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int solution(string S)
    {
        char[] stringarray = S.ToCharArray();
        int slength = S.Length;
        int result = 0;
     //   string resultstring = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < slength; i++)
        {
            char Z = stringarray[i];

            if(char.IsUpper(Z) || char.IsLower(Z) || !char.IsDigit(Z))
            {
                while (char.IsUpper(Z) || char.IsLower(Z) && !char.IsDigit(Z))
                {
                    result += 1;
                 //   resultstring = result.ToString();
                }
            }
        }         
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Z` is not updated in the inner loop.

Comment: Could you *edit* the question to show some inputs and desired results?

Comment: *"A valid Substring is one that contain 1 upper case and no numbers"* This is highly ambiguous. It could be interpretted as "a valid substring is exactly one uppercase character", but that's probably not what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: @spender - I wouldn't say "highly" ambiguous. Probably not even ambiguous at all. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @Enigmativity Let's take a look at some problem strings: "A", "As", "A$", "aS", "AA". Can you tell which ones are valid without assumptions?

Comment: @Enigmativity AAAAA is a valid substring?

Comment: @spender - The requirement is "that contain at least 1 upper case and no numbers" - so all of them are valid.

Comment: @xanatos - Yes, it meets the requirement.

Comment: @spender sorry i have edited the question. base on the sample string the valid substring is "ThisIsValid" and its length is 11. So it should return 11.

Comment: @FutureDev, please confirm the assertions made above. For each of "A", "As", "A$", "aS", "AA", is any *invalid*?

Comment: @FutureDev And is thisIsValid a valid substring? (so the uppercase isn't the first letter?) because you wrote `is one that contain atleast 1 upper case`

Comment: @Enigmativity it should return the length of the longest substring in the given string. Given your example is should return 2 because "As" "aS" "AA" is valid because it contains atleast 1 uppercase and no numeric digits.

Comment: @xanatos yes because it contains atleast 1 upper case letter and no numbers.

Comment: @FutureDev ...but  "A$" contains atleast 1 uppercase and no numeric digits. Why is it not considered valid?

Comment: @FutureDev - I didn't give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static int solution(string S)
{
    return
        S
            .Split("1234567890".ToCharArray()) // split on invalid characters
            .Where(x => x.Any(y => char.IsUpper(y))) // keep only those portions containing an uppercase char
            .Select(x => x.Length) // get the length of each string
            .Max(); // find the longest
}
```

---

Here's a solution based around the code in the question:

```
public static int solution(string S)
{
    int result = 0;
    int tally = 0;
    bool foundUpper = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
    {
        char Z = S[i];

        if (char.IsDigit(Z))
        {
            if (foundUpper && tally > result)
            {
                result = tally;
            }
            tally = 0;
            foundUpper = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tally++;
            foundUpper |= char.IsUpper(Z);
        }
    }
    if (foundUpper && tally > result)
    {
        result = tally;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

And a third option:

```
public static int solution3(string S)
{
    return S.ToCharArray().Concat(new [] { '0' }).Aggregate(
        new { result = 0, tally = 0, foundUpper = false },
        (a, x) => char.IsDigit(x)
            ? new { result = (a.foundUpper && a.tally > a.result) ? a.tally : a.result, tally = 0, foundUpper = false }
            : new { result = a.result, tally = a.tally + 1, foundUpper = a.foundUpper || char.IsUpper(x) })
        .result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some explaination: He is splitting the string at any number (because they are invalid), then reduces the selection to all those that contain upper characters. Afterwards he converts the elements into their separate length and returns the largest of them.

Comment: It is working sir but I'm sorry i can't understand your code as of now(I will study it in the future). Can you tweak my code so that it works? It will help me learn my mistake.

Comment: @FutureDev - Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int solution(string s)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            bool containsUpper = false;
            if (Char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            {
                int len = 0;
                do 
                {
                    if (Char.IsUpper(s[i])){
                        containsUpper = true;
                    }
                    i++;
                    len++;


                } while (i<s.Length&&Char.IsLetter(s[i])) ;

                if( (len > result )&&containsUpper)
                    result = len;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Answer has been updated to compile and give proper result, Downvote can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.

Answer (score 1):

The code is totally different from what you were writing. You are looking for substrings of not-digits, and then at the end of those substrings you have to check if at least one of the characters of the substring was upper case. If yes then this substring could be a candidate, and then its length must be considered. The check for the presence of the upper case character is done through the `upperCaseFound` boolean variable.

```
public static int LongestSubstring(string s)
{
    int maxLength = 0;

    bool upperCaseFound = false;
    int length = 0;

    foreach (char ch in s)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(ch))
        {
            if (upperCaseFound && length > maxLength)
            {
                maxLength = length;
            }

            upperCaseFound = false;
            length = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (char.IsUpper(ch))
        {
            upperCaseFound = true;
        }

        length++;
    }

    if (upperCaseFound && length > maxLength)
    {
        maxLength = length;
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir the code helped me understand the solution more.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this while loop

```
while (char.IsUpper(Z) || char.IsLower(Z) && !char.IsDigit(Z))
```

This will run indefinitely because you do not update `Z` inside the loop. So it can never change, and no change results in no exit point.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int MaxValid(string input)
    {
        var max = 0;
        var current = 0;
        bool upper = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(input, i))
            {
                if (upper && current > max)
                    max = current;

                current = 0;
                upper = false;
            }
            else
            {
                current++;
                if (char.IsUpper(input, i))
                    upper = true;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use String.Split with all digit characters to get all substrings, then check which ones "contain 1 upper case" and get the max length:

```
        string S = "a02caa3ThisIsValid1bC2a";
        S.Split("0123456789".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(u => u.ToCharArray().Count(c => Char.IsUpper(c)) == 1)
            .Max(s => s.Length);
```

Comment: I'm quite intersted why someone downvoted this. This solution:
gives correct result,
fast,
very simple code
and uses more than optimal memory.
I agree with the last but unless the substrings' number is not very much, it is a very good solution.
Downvoter, please write your opinion here,  or in private.
Thanks.